# Who or what decides what gets put into `loaddefs.el`?

Tags: autoload

For context, I'm writing an extension.

I need to check if a particular symbol is an autoload symbol, such that `autoloadp` = `t`.

After doing some digging I found that the defined autoloads in `loaddefs.el` do not match up with every declared autoload in the repository.

Check these screenshots out for clarity:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

As shown, symbol `org-capture-string` is declared to be an autoload, which is accurately reflected in the `loaddefs.el` file.

But symbols `orgtbl-exp-regexp` and `org-table-to-lisp` are also declared to be an autoload, which is inaccurately reflected in the `loaddefs.el` file, since they are no where to be found.

What gives?

Comment: Which version of Emacs?

Comment: @phils Currently using the master branch. Are those symbols (and all others for that matter) accurately reflected in the `loaddefs.el` file in the most recent release?

Comment: I'm also seeing this pattern with the `finder-inf.el` file. `cl-macs` is clearly a built-in Emacs package, but it's no where to be found in the `finder-inf.el` file

Answer (score 1):

`loaddefs.el` is automatically generated at build time. See `src/Makefile.in` line 774 (in whatever version I happened to have checked out; it might be a different line in yours).

Comment: How is the `cus-load.el` file even generated when the function `custom-make-dependencies` isn't even defined? https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/3af9e84ff59811734dcbb5d55e04e1fdb7051e77/lisp/Makefile.in#L154. Am I missing something?

Comment: Note the `-l cus-dep` on that line. This tells it to load the `cus-dep.el` file first, where `custom-make-dependencies` is located. Since that function isn’t needed most of the time, it isn’t even marked for autoloading. You can `load` the file if you want: `(load "cus-dep")`

Comment: not sure how I skipped over that when grepping for it; thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the org loaddefs in org-loaddefs.el, due to the file-local variable generated-autoload-file.

cl-macs is not a package, it is an internal component of cl-lib, which is in finder-inf.el.

Comment: What's the difference between a feature/package/library/internal-component? Can you give any examples of each and where that's explained in the documentation?

Comment: It’s all documented in [chapter 27.8 Libraries of Lisp Code for Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html) as well as [chapter 48 Emacs Lisp Packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual. (You can also use the built–in Info viewer to read the Emacs manuals, type `C-h i` to open it.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @db48x said, this is how it happens, and how you can yourself update `loaddefs.el` (or another file of autoloads). `C-h f batch-update-autoloads` tells us:

> **`batch-update-autoloads`** is an autoloaded Lisp function in
> `autoload.el`.
>
> `(batch-update-autoloads)`
>
> **Update `loaddefs.el` autoloads in batch mode.**
>
> Calls `update-directory-autoloads` on the command line arguments.
> Definitions are written to `generated-autoload-file` (which
> should be non-`nil`).

See also `update-directory-autoloads`, `update-file-autoloads`, and `w32-batch-update-autoloads`.

Comment: So from my understanding, someone forgot to update `ldefs-boot.el` for the symbols `orgtbl-exp-regexp` and `org-table-to-lisp` (in my example (I'm assuming there are others as well))?